# Why pytorch DataLoader behaves differently on numpy array and list?

Tags: python, list, numpy, iterator, pytorch

The **only** difference is one of the parameter passed to DataLoader is in type "numpy.array" and the other is in type "list", but the DataLoader gives totally different results.

You can use the following code to reproduce it:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader,Dataset
import numpy as np

class my_dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self,data,label):
        self.data=data
        self.label=label          
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index],self.label[index]
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

train_data=[[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[11,12,13],[15,16,17]]
train_label=[-1,-2,-11,-12]

########################### Look at here:    

test=DataLoader(dataset=my_dataset(np.array(train_data),train_label),batch_size=2)
for i in test:
    print ("numpy data:")
    print (i)
    break


test=DataLoader(dataset=my_dataset(train_data,train_label),batch_size=2)
for i in test:
    print ("list data:")
    print (i)
    break
```

The result is:

```
numpy data:
[tensor([[1, 2, 3],
        [5, 6, 7]]), tensor([-1, -2])]
list data:
[[tensor([1, 5]), tensor([2, 6]), tensor([3, 7])], tensor([-1, -2])]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because how batching is handled in [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader). `collate_fn` argument decides how samples from samples are merged into a single batch. Default for this argument is undocumented [`torch.utils.data.default_collate`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7edfe11ba49c8539ee904f06320050916857c8fe/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py#L196).

This function handles batching by assuming numbers/tensors/ndarrays are primitive data to batch and lists/tuples/dicts containing these primitives as structure to be (recursively) preserved. This allow you to have a semantic batching like this:

1. `(input_tensor, label_tensor) -> (batched_input_tensor, batched_label_tensor)`
2. `([input_tensor_1, input_tensor_2], label_tensor) -> ([batched_input_tensor_1, batched_input_tensor_2], batched_label_tensor)`
3. `{'input': input_tensor, 'target': target_tensor} -> {'input': batched_input_tensor, 'target': batched_target_tensor}`

(Left side of `->` is output of dataset[i], while right side is batched sample from `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`)

Your example code is similar to example 2 above: list structure is preserved while `int`s are batched.

Comment: Source: I added support for dicts to `DataLoader` in this [PR](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/1354/files).

Comment: May I ask what is a "mini-batch" in the official doc: "collate_fn (callable, optional) – merges a list of samples to form a mini-batch."  ?

Comment: May I understand it like this:  when it is a numpy array, the "if"  [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7edfe11ba49c8539ee904f06320050916857c8fe/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py#L210) is true, and when it is a list, the "if" [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7edfe11ba49c8539ee904f06320050916857c8fe/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py#L230) is True

Comment: Is mini-batch just batch?

Comment: Yep, mini-batch is just a batch. As explained in my answer numpy arrays are batched but list structure is preserved.